# "Riemannian" collar theorem

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact manifold of dimension $n$ with  boundary. If $\partial M$ is smooth then one has a control on the determinant of the Jacobian of the diffeomorphism  in the collar theorem, i.e. for $\epsilon$ small enough the diffeomorphism $F:\partial M\times (0,\epsilon)\to M_\epsilon$ can be given by $F(x,t)=\exp_x(t\,{\bf n}(x))$. Moreover there exist a universal constant $C>0$ such that $C^{-1}\le|\det DF|\le C$ (one can take C=2 here). Let say that a family of manifolds satisfies a "Riemannian collar theorem" if for each manifold in the family there exists a collar diffeomorphism  $F$ with a **universal** bounded on $|\det DF|$ as above.  Does the family of manifolds with piecewise smooth boundary satisfies a "Riemannian collar theorem"?  For example,  assume that $\partial M=\cup_{i=1}^m N_i$, where $N_i$ are smooth $(n-1)$-manifolds, and each point of singularity lies on a transversal intersection of exactly two elements of $\{N_i\}$. Do we have a "Riemannian  collar theorem" for such family of $(M,g)$? Probably not in general but can we say anything about when it does?

Comment: I'm no expert, but there's a [collar neighbourhood theorem for topological manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703009/collar-neighbourhoods-for-topological-manifolds). Might be worth looking at the proof to see if you can adapt their ideas.

Comment: It's not super clear to me what a collar neighborhood theorem means here. Does the unit square have a collar neighborhood? (Certainly I can't see the corner singularities on the interior.) One thing that is clearly true is that each smooth face has a collar neighborhood (this is obvious for the square).

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks for your remark.  I agree that the question was very ambiguous. Please see the edited version.

Comment: you probably want to mumble compact if you want a universal constant for one manifold.

Comment: @ThomasRot Yes, indeed. I forgot to put the assumption. Also by a universal constant, I meant  a constant independent of the family of manifolds under consideration.

Comment: Wouldn't a family with a singularity degenerating to nontransverse intersection provide a counterexample? For example, a family of "teardrop" domains in the plane, where the teardrop angle goes to zero.